# Easy sitemap.xml url

Tags: templates, htaccess, xml, rewrite

I've been looking for an easy way to point search engines to the sitemap.xml file in the **root of the website**. I've been using **Google Sitemap Lite** in combination with Navee or Structure. And it's generating sitemap.xml output like a charm.

But I've put the code in a template group named "sitemap". So I need to edit the **.htaccess** file, so the **/sitemap.xml** url points to **/index.php?/sitemap**. I couldn't get it to work...

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier approach to this!

In the template group, the one that contains the template that is used for the homepage of your site, I've added an **xml template** and named it **"sitemap.xml"**. The actual template filename becomes sitemap.xml.xml, and added the template code to generate the sitemap.xml structure.

This in combination with the **standard .htaccess file for "nice urls"** (see below), browsing to /sitemap.xml renders the sitemap.xml template I've just made.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This is not a great invention, but it could save some people some time.

Comment: I guess you need to disable strict_urls for this to work. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: So, why not to keep everything together? Instead of to use mod_rewrite, to disable the strict_urls and to name a file on a tricky way, you can use just the mod_rewrite and point right to "index.php/template_group/sitemap".